# should i change the urls website seo

Tags: seo, google-search

hello im renewing my website using a another CMS and i wanderd if i should use new dirs name for the content.

**example:**

i have a keyword that im showing up the first in google under the domain

**www.domain.com/content/view/articleName**

in the new website it caled

**www.domain.com/blog/articleTitle**

the reason is because i have also

**www.domain.com/news/articleTitle**

**www.domain.com/events/eventName**

will it b bad for my seo?,

how should i do it corectly?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for SEO advice. It might be on-topic on [webmasters.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that url's are same as before, with same content on it, otherwise you may lost rankings.

Or you can 301 redirect old url to new one, but that's not recommended because not all link juice will be passed and you may lost few ranking positions.